# cudaMalloc returns same memory address on different CPU threads

Tags: c, cuda, mpi, memory-address

I am trying to hunt down a bug in my program. It produces

```
[vaio:10404] Signal: Segmentation fault (11) 
[vaio:10404] Signal code: Address not mapped (1) 
[vaio:10404] Failing at address: 0x210000
[vaio:10405] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0) [0x7fa7857ffcb0]
[vaio:10405] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x14fe20) [0x7fa785580e20]
[vaio:10405] [ 2] /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1(+0x1b1f49) [0x7fa78676bf49]
```

`0x210000` is an address living in GPU memory. I have no unified address space in place (due to card limitations: sm_12).

The problem occurs when running the program through `mpiexec -n 2`. That is, I start 2 CPU processes, both create their own context on the same (!) GPU (just 1 GPU installed). Like this:

```
cuInit(0);
cuDeviceGet(&cuDevice, 0); // get device number 0
cuCtxCreate(&cuContext, 0, cuDevice); // create context
cuMemAlloc( &mem , size );  // allocate memory pool (hundreds of MB)
```

(This is simplified here - all cuda calls are checked for error returns)

I am using this setup very successfully for quite some time now (multiple host processes sharing the same GPU). However, that was when using the CUDA runtime API. Now, I am switching to the driver API.

To hunt this down I dump out `mem` of the above code. Turns out that the memory address that is returned by `cuMemAlloc` is the same for both processes! This wonders me. Here the dump out:

```
process 0: allocate internal buffer: unaligned ptr = 0x210000  aligned ptr = 0x210000
process 1: allocate internal buffer: unaligned ptr = 0x210000  aligned ptr = 0x210000
```

Immediately I checked with my old code (runtime API) which never has such problems. Turns out it reports on both processes (sharing the same device) the same memory address as well. This has never drawn my attention before.

I find this hard to believe. Just to make this clear: Both processes request device memory with `cudaMalloc` (runtime API) and `cuMalloc` (driver API) (400MB on a big card), and both processes get the same address returned?
I am sure that not one process is advancing a lot and already freed the memory, so that the first process can reuse the same memory because the first process has already terminated. No, this memory is used as a memory pool to serves subsequent memory allocations and there are a lot of synchronization points in between. The pool is freed at program termination.

Anybody knows how the same pointer value (memory address) can be reported to both processes but on the GPU this refers to different memory? (It must since the calculations it carries out are correct. And that wouldn't be the case if the memory pools overlapped). To my knowledge this is not possible. What am I missing?

Comment: talonmies is right. It is no different than getting the same address in two different CPU processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the concept of virtual addressing.

Each CPU thread has its own CUcontext, and each CUcontext has its own GPU *virtual* address space. The addresses returned from the API are virtual, and host driver and/or device performs virtual address translation into absolute addresses in GPU memory. There is plenty of evidence that the GPU has a dedicated TLB onboard for precisely this purpose.

Comment: That would assume that it is possible that a successful `cuMalloc` returns the same value on different CPU threads. And since virtual to real address mapping is done with the help of dedicated hardware (as you say) there is no way to tell the real address from the application point of view.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, and that is the reason that some GPU APIs use opaque buffer objects to represent memory allocations rather than bare pointers. The application isn't suppose to be able or need to know very much about what GPU addresses mean.